I set a cookie from backend but the frontend requests are not able to include this cookie in the requests
I can see the cookie in the setHeaders for the login route .this is how i made request from frontend
const response = await fetch(apiurl, {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include',
});

server responds with a status code of 401
I removed the samesite from here
res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, {
  httpOnly: true,
  maxAge: 168 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
})

Frontend is running on localhost but on port 3000 and the backend is also  running on localhost but port 3500
Is this considered as a cross site request? I tried using sameSite:'None' and secure as false as the requests are served over http and not https. The code is running in dev environment
sameSite:'Lax' does not work as well because the request does not change the url and is not a top navigation request.
The refresh token that was set as a cookie in the browser does not get included. I can see other cookies passed by the browser but this cookie is ignored, what should I do?

Duplicate: I am unable to set the cookies received from the response

Hi, Yes it is considered as a cross origin request since the two origins differ by port number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. As Phil has answered, every request including the very first request which resulted the Cookie should also be invoked with credentials : include.

Thankyou for replying !. Are you saying the login route that sets the cookie should be invoked from frontend by including credentials ? why do we need to do that the login route do not need cookies in anyway. what should i do should i set samesite to lax or None since the request that needs cookies is not a toplevel request so lax maynot work and sameSite None requires https:// it will not work for dev environment or maybe i am not getting something
